# live stream recording in flex

Tags: apache-flex, video, encoding, h.264, live-streaming

I want to `record a live stream in flex` for that what i am doing is i am capturing the image of the videoDisplay element which is showing the video 15 frames per second which looks like a video.I am doing this by adding a actionlistener of timer event. and parralelly i am also recording audio in binary array .

Does anyone have another solution for live streaming a video in flex??

i want to `encode the videos in H264` or such kind of encoder what do i have to do for `flex` ???

How can i get continuous frames of video recording from the camera object to send it or store it ?

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following  link will going to be very useful to you..

[Click](http://www.igorcosta.com/flex3/doc/flash/net/NetStream.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but  it requires flash media server and as i stated i just want to get the data as byte array and i will send it through sockets to other machine so i don`t want to use any server in between. So what can i do else?

Comment: Link in answer is dead.

Answer (score 2):

You need a media server for doing this. There are many of them: Adobe Flash Media Server, Red5, Wowza.
I used Red5, it already contains simple server application and ActionScript code.

Comment: I just want to capture the video and not want to send anywhere. I want to send it through the socket still do i need to install server ?

Comment: It seems that currently Flash doesn't support live encoding to H264. You can encode to H264 using media server or use P2P with lower quality.

Comment: Its fine i just want to encode using some codec i don`t know which codec is best in flex so i told H264